# How to calculate the number of lines of code within a program?

Tags: java

I want to calculate the number of lines of code within a program, and for which I had already written code which counts the number of `;`. It works fine, but not in some situations like where there is no `;` present (like `if` and `while` statements). In this case I had stored some of the keywords in an array of strings and I want to search for that keyword by using `readLine()`. If it works fine then I will increment it by 1, but it's not working. I had tried a lot but it is not working at all, and it is showing the Exception. As `Demo.java` you can use your own code.

**Classdetect1.java**

```
import java.io.*;
public class Classdetect1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        int i=0,j=0,k=0,p;
        String str1[]={"if","else","else if","while","for","goto","do"};

        // Open the file
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("Demo.java");



        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        String strLine;

        if (in == null){
            System.out.println("File is blank");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while (i != -1)
        {
            i = in.read();
            if(i==';' || i=='{')
            {
                j=j+1;
            }

            if(i=='\'')
            {
                while(in.read()!='\'')
                    continue;
            }

            if(i=='\"')
            {
                while(in.read()!='\"')
                    continue;
            }

            if(i=='(')
            {
                while(in.read()!=')')
                    continue;
            }


            while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                for(p=0;p<7;p++)
                {
                    if(str[p].equals(strLine))
                    {
                        k=k+1;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Line of =" + k);
        }
        System.out.println("Total Line of code=" + j);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is _the Exception_, and where does _it_ occur?

Comment: Consider writing a parser, read up on Antlr

Comment: `str[p].equals(strLine)` , where have you defined array named `str`  ?

Comment: @NoobUnChained Maybe he meant to write `strLine`.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen What about sloccount?

Comment: @DennisMeng no idea, is it a standard command somewhere?

Comment: It was shown to me as an alternative to `wc -l` for counting lines, since sloccount is supposed to account for whitespace, lines with just a closing brace, etc

Answer (score 0):

In Java all statements end either with `;` or with a block within `{` `}`. Some examples:

```
System.out.println("One statement");

while (str.equals("One block of statements + one statement"))
{
    System.out.println("One statement");
}
```

Furthermore, the `;` does not need to be on the same line at all:

```
System.out.println(
    "One statement"
);
```

So you could simply count all `;` (end of a statement) and all `{` (end of a statement, start of a block) and it will be fairly accurate.

```
if (true)
{                               // One statement ending with '{'
    doSomething();              // One statement ending with ';'
    while (false)
    {                           // One statement ending with '{'
        doSomethingElse();      // One statement ending with ';'
    }
}
// 4 statements in total.
```

Of course, there are (as always) some exceptions:

```
if (true) doSomething();  // One statement, or two?

do { doSomething(); } while (true); // Three statements, or two?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:/lines.txt")));
String s = "";
String text = "";

//save all the file in a string
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    text += s + "\n";
}

//remove empty lines with a regex
String withoutEmptyLines = text.replaceAll("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "");

//lines of code = text with newline characters length - text without newline characters length
int linesOfCode = withoutEmptyLines.length() - withoutEmptyLines.replaceAll("\n", "").length();
System.out.println("Lines: "+linesOfCode);
```

My `C:/lines.txt` file:

```
01. a
02. 
03. b
04. c
05. c
06. d
07. as
08. d
09. asd
10. asd
11. a
12. 
13. 
14. 
15. asd
16. 
17. asd
18. 
19. 
20. 
21. asdasd
22. 
23. 
24.
```

With this file, the output is:

```
Lines: 13
```

Hope this helps